# Changing from divisi to multiple parts (Sibelius)

Tags: engraving, arranging, sibelius

I am currently arranging a piece which has a few divisi parts. I will use the clarinets as the example for this question. There are two of them, and at the beginning (when they are not playing) I want them grouped together **on the same staff**, labelled as "Clarinets" with 1 and 2 written vertically next to the label and in front of the staff.

Later on in the piece, I want the two clarinet parts to be on **separate staffs**, but labelled together as "cl." with a bracket containing both staffs. I also want the staffs to be labelled "1" and "2" respectively.

Does anyone know how to achieve the above on Sibelius? I'm using Sibelius Ultimate v. 2020.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have 3 staves for these two clarinet parts: Clarinet 1, Clarinet 2 and a stave for both. When you have music on split staves, hide the combined stave; when you have music on the combined stave, hide the individual staves.

And when you do the parts you can either have both clarinet parts on one part (common with horn and string parts), again hiding where staves are blank, or you can have clarinet 1 and the combined stave and clarinet 2 with the combined stave.

Comment: This post gives some more info: http://www.sibelius.com/cgi-bin/helpcenter/chat/chat.pl?com=thread&start=638772&groupid=3&&guest=1. Sibelius is very powerful, so there are doubtless other solutions…

Comment: Thanks. How do you get "1" and "2" lined up vertically in front of the combined staff?

Comment: @yerman It's not usual or necessary to have the numbers vertically aligned. "Clarinet 1, 2" on one line works fine.